# Returning a promise within a promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

What's the most kosher way of getting the desired result WITHOUT nesting both promised within a new promise and calling resolve/reject?

Example

```
const transferFile = (fileName, bucketName)=>{
    const destinationBucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);
    return exists =  destinationBucket.file(fileName).exists()
        .then(exists=>{
            if(exists[0]){
                return true;
            } else {

                // calling another method that returns a promise

                return file.move(destinationBucket)
                    .then(yay=>{

                        // return yay

                        return yay;
                    });

            }
        });

}

transferFile(image, 'bucketName')
    .then(exists=>{
        console.log(exists);
        transferFile(video, 'bucketName');
    })

    // getting undefined rather than yay

    .then(yay)...
```

I wish to return the `yay` value from `file.move` to the base promise chain. Currently no thrown errors from `file.move` will be caught in the base promise chain, nor is the value of `yay` being passed.

Comment: Does this work?  `return exists =  destinationBucket.file(fileName)` And add rejection handlers if you want to see errors.

Comment: Don't you need `return transferFile(video, 'bucketName');`?

Comment: Shilly, it does and the catch handler is down the promise chain. torazaburo, thanks. That was a pretty bad brain fart. I should get some sleep lol.

Comment: You should drop that global variable assingment `exists =  ` after the `return`

Comment: Bergi, yeah. was just just doing that to test if it was returning the right thing. good catch though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transferFile` returns the promise, but you discard it in the second call.

So notice that I return it within the `then` function.

```
transferFile(image, 'bucketName')
    .then(exists=>{
        console.log(exists);
        return transferFile(video, 'bucketName');
    })

    // getting undefined rather than yay

    .then(yay)...
```